# Loading batch files in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want load many files from a directory that their names have a pattern such as: ***data_1*** &  ***data_2*** , ... , that as mentioned, the numbers in each "data_" are as the same with the counter of the main `for` loop.

How can I do this for matching the file names that are loading with the number of counter of the `for` loop. This is my imperfect code:

```
for i=1:100
loadpath='./folder/data/';
 load('Label_i.mat');
end
```

Comment: You can try: `load(['Label_' num2str(i) '.mat'])`; Beside, what's the purpose of having `loadpath='./folder/data/';` in each iteration if it do not change and it is not used?

Comment: You can use `sprintf` with the `%i` format spec:`load(sprintf('Label_%i.mat', i));`

Comment: @il_raffa, Thank for your comment, I want load files from a specific path, but I think this solution does not solve that. Any ideas?

Comment: @rinkert, thanks, How can I read from the aforementioned directory?

Comment: If you want to add the path, you can either just `load(sprintf('./folder/data/Label_%i.mat', i));` or use `fullfile`: `load(fullfile(loadpath, sprintf('Label_%i.mat', i)));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`fullfile`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) and [`sprintf`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
loadpath='./folder/data/';
for k = 1:100
    load(fullfile(loadpath, sprintf('Label_%i.mat', k)));
end
```

Comment: In the case, when the saved data in the disk, starts for example from ***data_125***, ***data_126*** , ..., with considering that the counter of the main loop starts from 1 to N, How the code can be adapted for this aim?

Comment: Could you clarify your folder/file name structure (perhaps in the question body)? I don't understand what you are trying to do now. Just add the update at the bottom with sufficient details.